# Repeated writing in different XMLfiles

Tags: c#, xml, invalidoperationexception

I need to write GPS-Data in different XMLfiles. The files need to have the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<gpx>
<metadata>
<time>YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ</time>
</metadata>
<trk>
<name>YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ</name>
<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="12.1795" lon="12.3456">
<ele>-46.97</ele>
<time>YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ</time>
</trkpt>
// more trkpt
</trkseg>
</trk>
</gpx>
```

I tried to do it with an XMLwriter. At first it constructs the part till trkpt.That works. The XmlWriterSettings were included because the Error told me to use ConformanceLevel "Auto" or "fregmented" ,but that didn't solve my issue.

```
XmlWriterSettings setting = new XmlWriterSettings();
setting.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto;
setting.Indent = true;

DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
xmlWriter[0] = XmlWriter.Create("testbase.xml", setting);      
for (int i = 1; i < (numOfXMLWriter); i++)      
{
    xmlWriter[i] = XmlWriter.Create(test[i].Text, setting);      
}
int tmp = 0;
foreach (XmlWriter writer in xmlWriter)
{
writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
writer.WriteStartElement("gpx");
writer.WriteStartElement("metadata");
writer.WriteStartElement("time");
writer.WriteString(localDate.Year + "-" + localDate.Month + "-" + localDate.Day + "T" + localDate.Hour + ":" + localDate.Minute + ":" + localDate.Second);
writer.WriteEndElement();       //time
writer.WriteEndElement();       //metadata
                                //trk + name
writer.WriteStartElement("trkseg");

}
```

Later the received GPS-Data is written as individual trkpt.

```
xmlWriter[id].WriteStartElement("trkpt");
xmlWriter[id].WriteAttributeString("lat", splitData[4]);
xmlWriter[id].WriteAttributeString("lon", splitData[6]);
xmlWriter[id].WriteStartAttribute("ele");
xmlWriter[id].WriteString("0");  
xmlWriter[id].WriteEndElement();        //</ele>
xmlWriter[id].WriteStartElement("time");
xmlWriter[id].WriteString(splitData[10][4] + splitData[10][5] + "-" + splitData[10][2] + splitData[10][3] + "-" + splitData[10][0] + splitData[10][1] + "T" + splitData[2][0] + splitData[2][1] + ":" + splitData[2][2] + splitData[2][3] + ":" + splitData[2][4] + splitData[2][5] + "Z");
xmlWriter[id].WriteEndElement();        //</time>
xmlWriter[id].WriteEndElement();        //</trkpt>
```

The Error says:

```
InvalidOperationException: "Token StartElement in state EndRootElement would result in an invalid XML document”
```

I think this is because the XMLwriter Closes all the nodes atomatically and later i try to add another Node on root Level. Is there a possibility to stap the writer from ending the document on it's own?
Thanks for your help!
Jonas

Comment: I'd guess your start / end calls are unbalanced. But my real question is: why are you using `XmlWriter` directly? It's really hard work and easy to get wrong (as you've demonstrated). Why not use LINQ to XML?

Comment: Even if you want to work with `XmlWriter`, why do you start writing XML before you have GPS data?

Comment: @CharlesMager I dindn't know about LinqToXml, I'm gonna try it with that!

Comment: @DmitryOgurtsov I want to write the metadata etc. first end then append the trkpts. The first part is in another method, so i Need to call it first and then write every single GPS point

Comment: @Jonas In this case you should not use `XmlWriter`, indeed LINQ to XML seems the better option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\" ?><gpx></gpx>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(header);
            XElement gpx = doc.Root;

            gpx.Add(new object[] {
                new XElement("metadata"), new XElement("time", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddthh:mm:ssz")),
                new XElement("trk",  new object[] {
                    new XElement("name", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddthh:mm:ssz")),
                    new XElement("trksseg", new object[] {
                        new XElement("trkpt", new object[] {
                            new XAttribute("lat", 12.1795),
                            new XAttribute("lon", 12.3456),
                            new XElement("ele", -46.97),
                            new XElement("time",DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddthh:mm:ssz")),
                        })
                    })
                })
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine! Thanks alot. I am able to add the another trkpt in with this code:

`XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
                        xDoc.Element("gpx").Element("trk").Element("trksseg").Add(new XElement("trkpt", new object[] {
                            new XAttribute("lat", splitData[4]),
                            new XAttribute("lon", splitData[6]),
                            new XElement("ele", 0),
                            new XElement("time",DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddthh:mm:ssz")) }));
                        xDoc.Save(FILENAME);`

Comment: Your can use : XElemement trksseg = doc.Descendants("trksseg").FirstOrDefault();  Then trksseg.Add(....);  Descenetandants returns a list() so using FirstOrDefault() get the first element.

Comment: Okay, that makes the Code easier.
But something, maybe LinqToXML, adds three invisible Hex values to the start of the File 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF.
I tried deleting them with Filestream, but can't find a way to remove them.
`using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) {;
                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                        {
                            stream.Position = 0;
                            stream.WriteByte(null);    //cannot convert from <null> to byte
                        }
                    }`

Comment: The characters must be in the string "header" I posted.  Can't be any place else.  Try removing from the string.  Try retyping the beginning of the string.  Why are you opening the file as ReadWrite?  Maybe they are already in the file.

Comment: It's called Byte Order Mark (BOM) and the Tool i use to analyze the GPS data can't read the Data if it starts with the BOM.
Solution: Before saving read the whole file, do a string Operation and write it back to the file ->
`string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(FILENAME);
                    lines[0] = lines[0].Substring(0);
                    File.WriteAllLines(FILENAME);`